# Render doesnt replace old component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to inject `Switcher10` to the `container` dom,

```
render(
    <Switcher10 buttonId={containerid} displayText="AutoReply" isChecked={false} meta={meta}/>,
    container,
  )
```

`Switcher10` looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

interface Props {
  displayText: string
  buttonId?: number
  isChecked?: boolean
  meta?: string
}


const Switcher10 = (props: Props) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isChecked) setIsChecked(props.isChecked)
  }, [])

  console.log('Switcher10:propsmighthavechanged', props)

  const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label className="autoSaverSwitch relative inline-flex cursor-pointer select-none items-center">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="autoSaver"
          className="sr-only"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
        />
        <span
          className={`slider mr-3 flex items-center rounded-full p-1 duration-200 ${
            isChecked ? 'bg-indigo-500' : 'bg-[#CCCCCE]'
          }`}
        >
          <span
            className={`dot rounded-full bg-white duration-200 ${
              isChecked ? 'translate-x-6' : ''
            }`}
          ></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </>
  )
}

export default Switcher10
```

The thing is if the `container` dom already has `Switcher10` it is not even calling the `Switcher10` React component.

It is important for me to replace old `Switcher10` with new one as the values of props have changed or be able to pass the updated props. Either is fine but neither is happening by simple `render()`.

It is actually going in `Switcher10` as `console.log('Switcher10:propsmighthavechanged', props)` print the new value of props but the react html doesnt rerender with new values.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass something as the `state` into the `props` of `Switcher10` so any updates of the `props` will trigger a re-render of the `Switcher10` component.

In fact, `State` change is always the primary way to trigger re-render, check the below code (I write it in `useState()` considering you are mainly using functional components):

```
// somewhere above your render()
const [props, setProps] = useState({
    displayText: '',
    buttonId: '',
    isChecked: false,
    meta: '',
}) // change if you want any other initial value.

render(
    <Switcher10 buttonId={props.buttonId} displayText="AutoReply" isChecked={props.isChecked} meta={props.meta}/>,
    container,
  )
```

And when you want to update the values of the `props`:

```
const someAction = () => {
    // do whatever action you need.
    setProps({
        displayText: '[newValue]',
        buttonId: '[newValue]',
        isChecked: true,
        meta: '[newValue]',
    })
}
```

---

Besides, one of the benefits of using `hooks` in functional components than `setState()` in class components is that, the `state` can be interacted with seperately:

```
// Through using hooks,
const [displayText, setText] = useState('');
const [buttonId, setId] = useState('');
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
const [meta, setMeta] = useState('');

// each value can be updated independently (somewhere in a function, etc.),
const someAction = () => {
    // do whatever action you need.
    setText('[newValue]');
    setIsChecked(true);
}

// and thus,
render(
    <Switcher10 buttonId={buttonId} displayText="AutoReply" isChecked={isChecked} meta={meta}/>,
    container,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

moved the `isChecked` changing logic to parent component and passed that function down

Parent:

```
const changeIsCheckedPermanently = (meta: string, newValue: boolean) => {
  myMap.set(meta, true)
}

render(
    <Switcher10 buttonId={containerid} displayText="AutoReply" isChecked={myMap.get(meta)} meta={meta} changeIsCheckedPermanently={changeIsCheckedPermanently}/>,
    container,
  )
```

Now child component `Switcher10` no longer has a local `isChecked` variable.

`Switcher10`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

interface Props {
  displayText: string
  buttonId?: number
  changeIsCheckedPermanently: (meta: string, newValue: boolean) => void
  meta?: string
}


const Switcher10 = (props: Props) => {

  const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
    props.changeIsCheckedPermanently(props.meta, !props.isChecked)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label className="autoSaverSwitch relative inline-flex cursor-pointer select-none items-center">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="autoSaver"
          className="sr-only"
          checked={props.isChecked}
          onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
        />
        <span
          className={`slider mr-3 flex items-center rounded-full p-1 duration-200 ${
            props.isChecked ? 'bg-indigo-500' : 'bg-[#CCCCCE]'
          }`}
        >
          <span
            className={`dot rounded-full bg-white duration-200 ${
              props.isChecked ? 'translate-x-6' : ''
            }`}
          ></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </>
  )
}

export default Switcher10
```